# Do you edit questions in order to provide syntax highlighting?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, syntax-highlighting

I tend to answer questions related to specific plugins (see questions related to [`parsley.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsley.js), which is a jQuery plugin).

More often than not, the OP simply adds the tag of the plugin. However, if she/he adds code to the question, or if I add code to my answer, there will be no syntax highlighting.

It pains me to read code without syntax highlighting and sometimes you can spot the mistake simply by reading code.

Most times I edit the question and add the `[javascript]` tag, but I have seen some users reject my edit with the message:

> This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.

I understand that simply editing the tags is an easy way to gain those extra two reputation points, but it really helps anyone who visits the site.

What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Don't do it unless having the syntax highlighted makes a *substantial* improvement to readability of the post.  Often people do this to poor questions without even realizing that the changes are frivolous and contribute nothing, other than an entirely unjustified bumping of the question to the top of the page.

Comment: @Chris: Syntax highlighting seems substantial enough to me. If it's not important then why do we have it? If you don't like it you can turn it off with CSS magic but the rest of us like it.

Comment: It's not that I mind having words random colors, rather **I mind having questions bumped up in the queue for no useful reason**.  If the OP didn't do it originally, and having it makes no meaningful contribution to the answerability of the question, then *resist the urge to frivolously meddle*.  In the *rare* cases where it would actually help readability of something *key to the question*, then go ahead.

Comment: I've submitted a number of edits that only added or removed tags, and I don't think any of them have been rejected. Personally I think edits like this are substantive as they get the question shown to correct people.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Out of interest, is it merely the idea of question bumping that frustrates you or do you actually notice bumped questions in the queue and find that annoying? I, for one, never notice any.

Comment: I'm constantly seeing questions cycled back up for no reason other than people's insatiable urge to make tiny, irrelevant changes.

Comment: Who cares where the question is in the queue? That should never be a more important consideration than improving the quality of a question. The question might end up getting put on hold if it is not a good question, but if issues like tags or highlighting are fixed, that lets people focus on the substance of the question.

Comment: And my point is that these edits are making *tiny* changes which should not in any way distract from the substance, at least when read by anyone remotely prepared to help with that substance.  Conversely, having a lot of stale questions at the top of the page for *no good reason* does tend to remove attention from other questions which would be high on the page for *good reasons* (such as being new or *meaningfully improved*).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As a high-rep user, I will either edit tags to add a missing relevant tag, such as the JavaScript tag, or I will add [syntax-highlighting hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) to the Stack Exchange's Markdown parser:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    if (foo) {
      alert("Shazbot!");
    }
```

However, as a low-rep user like yourself, without full-editing privileges, I would try to improve the post as much as possible, if there are any other things that can be improved as well (grammar, spelling, missing punctuation, etc.).

If adding a missing relevant tag or adding syntax highlighting is the only thing to improve in a post, personally, I would approve such an edit, but I can see how a lot of other users would reject such edits as seemingly too minor.

If there's nothing else to improve in the post and your edit is still rejected, I would just move on and find another post to edit instead.

Comment: I second this: it's important when you don't have full editing privileges to correct *everything* that you could possibly correct in the post to get it through the Suggested Edits queue. More often than not, posts that could use an extra tag or some code formatting need some grammar and spelling fixes as well.

Comment: @Cupcake is there any list to see all markups, for instance I need for Objective-C. <!-- language: lang-Objective-C --> is this correct?

Comment: @mohacs Here is the [list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). I suggest you add that link to your answer CupCake (as reference).

Comment: I would say that an edit to a post, to add the tag for the mainstream programming language which the post is about, cannot be too minor. Of course, it is great if other issues with the post can be fixed as well. But I wouldn't reject the edit if it only fixes the major tag. I would however reject edits that only adds some minor tag, without fixing other issues in the post as well.

Comment: An improvement is an improvement no matter how minor it is. As long as it's not introducing an error why would you want to reject something like that?

Comment: @canon This has been discussed at length: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site. Seems like a notable portion of the community agrees with you. (I certainly do.)

Comment: @MattK The main argument seems to be that it clutters the "active" lists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Given the multiple answers and comments, I will only add a tag to provide syntax highlight when there are other issues with the questions or when I see that it really needs code highlight. For any other question, I will post a comment to suggest the OP to add the tag. As for me, I will aprove this kind of edits.

Comment: No, the only reason anyone cares about this @canon is because suggested edits have to be *reviewed* by other people—up to 3, I believe. Which is asking a lot of those people if you're making excessively trivial "minor" edits. Users with full edit privileges, on the other hand, can make edits without bothering anyone. So if they're doing anything at all productive, then they have carte blanche.

Comment: "If there's nothing else to improve in the post" **There is *always* something more to improve in a post.**

Comment: @bjb568 I disagree, sometimes there really *isn't* anything else that could be done to improve a post.

Comment: @Cupcake Really? I just edited your answer substantially. Just because your answer is great doesn't mean that no substantial correct edits are possible.

Comment: @bjb568 the edits that you made were *really* pushing it, there's not much you can do to improve my answer, outside of starting to change the meaning of what I wrote. Many of the edits that you made were indeed very minor changes that didn't really improve my answer all that much, if at all.

Comment: I made many minor changes which amounts too a non-minor edit. I don't see how it changes the meaning…

Comment: It wasn't a necessary edit as what you changed neither made it clearer or easier to understand... I would even argue it made it less clearer.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Less clear? Well… I don't think so.

Comment: @bjb568 well, it certainly didn't make it any *more* clear, for sure.

Comment: @Cupcake Well… I think it did…

Comment: @CodyGray "Which is asking a lot of those people if you're making excessively trivial 'minor' edits." Edits that change one or two words usually take about 30 seconds to review well. In my opinion, that policy itself is a bigger time sink; when I see an edit that actually represents a minor improvement (grammatical, spelling, formatting, whatever), I have to sit there and debate with myself: "Oh, this is actually a good change! But... it's a small change. Does it fall into 'too minor'?" Not to mention it leads to questions like this one and discourages people actually trying to help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59230/discussion-on-answer-by-cupcake-do-you-edit-questions-in-order-to-provide-syntax).

Comment: @bjb568 since you said "there's always something more to improve", what more could I have done with [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15205486)?

Answer (score 24):

Yes, this is fine.

The "too minor" edit reject phenomenon is a disease to be wiped out. The Stack Exchange servers can handle multiple incremental edits being made rather than one big one, so rejecting a small improvement on the basis that "other improvements could also have been made" is entirely ridiculous.

Comment: I just want to point out that some of the common arguments against minor edits are that: `(1)` they're an easy way to rep farm, `(2)`  they clog the review queues, and `(3)` they bump posts in the question lists too much. A fourth reason used to be because edits from enough people would cause a post to become community wiki, but of course that's not possible anymore.

Comment: For what it's worth, users on meta seem to worry far too much about rep farming. As an edit queue reviewer, speculation about what motivated the user to suggest the edit should have exactly nothing to do with your decision to accept or reject.

Comment: @AirThomas: Spot on.

Comment: I haven't been reviewing for long and I see plenty of users editing just enough or only 1 thing that needs improvement in questions/answers in all their edits (yes I look at the activity history of users I see multiple times in the same day in my reviews) that it looks awfully like someone farming rep cause there's about no other activity from them. It is a concern.

Comment: One of the issues with being able to earn rep by repeatedly making a bunch of minor edits to posts (perhaps even the same post) is that it makes it easier for people to [create sock puppets to start fraudulently upvoting their main accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268267/456814).

Comment: I think question bumping is also overrated as a major plague affecting Stack Overflow. I have never once been frustrated by a question bump, not sure I've ever even noticed one. Perhaps that's related to the tags I frequent, I don't know. Certainly the current level of "bumping" is quite fine with me, and yet we all still complain about too many trivial edits.

Comment: @Duncan: Hey, watch it there! We certainly don't "all" complain about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Stop complaining and please fit nicely into the pigeon-hole I've put you in! :-)

Comment: The rep farming aspect is nonsensical, the rep I received out of edits barely "funds" answer downvotes, and I'd argue it's one of the slowest ways to earn rep, there's even a cap for it. Honestly I'd rather SE just get rid of the paltry +2 rep if it bothers people so much, I'd rather just be able to fix things with the minimal amount of drama possible.

Answer (score 6):

If you are adding a tag to get better syntax highlighting, definitely make that clear in the edit description. Better syntax highlighting is good, but usually not very obvious from the diff that is shown to reviewers. So the additional syntax highlighting can be easily missed by the people reviewing your edit, making it look less important than it is.

So if your edit aims improve syntax highlighting, make sure to put attention to that in the edit comment.

Also, if there are additional problems with the post (spelling errors/...), do fix all of those problems, not just the highlighting.

Comment: Sometimes I don't have time to fix _everything_. Why should that be an excuse for people to throw back in my face the thing that I _did_ have time to fix? Now you're just wasting what little time I did volunteer to the cause.

Comment: Because you're wasting our time in the review edits queue.

Answer (score 2):

I would approve any correct edit that added a language-related tag, such as `[javascript]`. Simply by adding that tag, you ensure the question is seen by those people who can answer it. I would encourage you to make your edits more substantive than that if possible, but I wouldn't reject it if you didn't.

If you simply added syntax highlighting with a markdown hint:

```
<!-- language: javascript -->
```

I may well reject that as too minor if it were your only change. Prettifying code is not really a good enough reason to bring three edit reviewers into the debate.

Comment: Actually it does appear pretty evidently in every tab. For example http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25168636/revisions.

Comment: I would disapprove any edit which was merely *coincidental* to the question asked.  Code might be in a language, but unless the actual issue hinges on unique aspects of the language itself, or syntax highlighting makes a serious improvement in its readability, language tags not added by the OP really don't belong, and don't justify the implicit bumping to the top of the page.

Comment: @Sifu Yes, you're right. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I disagree; language tags are special, IMO. Many people browse SO using filters based on the languages they know. Adding a language tag ensures a question receives attention from the people who are most likely to help. The consequential syntax highlighting is an irrelevant bonus. I've also never been upset by seeing a bumped question, so I don't personally factor that into my decisions. Perhaps that is because I peruse high traffic tags.

Comment: If the language is important to the question, sure, but the tag shouldn't be applied (at least not by a 3rd party) if the question merely involves ideas which *happen* to be expressed in a given language, but could just as easily be in some other one.  There's a big difference between *relevant* vs *incidental*.

Answer (score 0):

"Too Minor" is there largely because you're spending someone's time (3 or more someones) to verify your edit when you're a low-rep user.  If you're just adding syntax highlighting, I'd say that is indeed too minor; it does add to the post, and when you hit 2k+ it's much appreciated, but it doesn't sufficiently take away from the reading of the post that it's worth taking so many peoples' time to do.

If the post has other issues, fix them as well; if it's a great question and just forgot syntax highlighting, add a comment.  Most questions without syntax highlighting need more work than just a tag, to be honest, so I suspect some/many of these rejections are because of that.

Comment: I'd still strongly argue against editing a post to add syntax highlighting *if having the highlighting serves no useful purpose*.  I recently pointed out to a *moderator* that their application of this (which changed the color of one numeric constant) was entirely pointless, as the actual problem of the question had nothing to do with the code sample to begin with.

Comment: If it serves no useful purpose, sure, but then why is the code sample there?

Comment: Isn't this a bit contra-productive? To me it seems the intent of reviewing low-rep edits is to guide these users to what a good edit policy is. With a reasoninglike this you teach a different policy to low-rep users (no format edits) than you eventually want from high-rep users (format edits because they are more readable).

Comment: @KillianDS The problem is more that we're trying to guide people to doing the other parts of edits: fixing up questions that are _bad_.  Discouraging them a bit from these kind of edits is worth it, if it means they pay more attention to bigger problems.

Comment: Then *everyone* should refrain from making frivolous edits

Comment: This isn't a difficult concept.  Value(minor edit) = 0.5.  Cost(approving minor edit)=3*0.3 = -0.9.  So, if you have no need of approval, go ahead and make it (but preferably make a bigger edit if possible).  Further, we're trying to train people to make bigger edits - assumably if you're over 2k, you've been sufficiently trained (not necessarily true, but that's the system) and don't need the more rigorous rules.

Comment: If low rep users aren't supposed to make minor changes, how exactly are we supposed to notify high rep users of problems? Trying to suggest edits in comments almost never works; I've got multi-year old comments saying "please add this" that nobody acted on.

Answer (score -8):

No.  I don't do it because I don't think it's worth doing.  I would rather spend time and effort asking, reading or answering an interesting question.  I don't have a problem with it, though -- it's okay if we disagree -- but I won't willingly spend my time on it.

My opinion on some of your points:

> It pains me to read code without syntax highlighting

It doesn't bother me.  As long as it's in a Markdown code block, I'm fine with it.

> sometimes you can spot the mistake simply by reading code.

Sounds like a junk question.  If the question is that easily answered, there's a good chance I won't be interested in reading it, regardless of syntax highlighting.

> it really helps anyone who visits the site.

I disagree.  *(EDIT: if you think that I'm categorically saying that syntax highlighting doesn't help anyone, then you're WRONG!  See the comments below for more explanation.)*

Comment: Why do you disagree? I would say the wrong markup looks pretty bad (I've seen HTML markup on VB.net, it was horrible).

Comment: @Matt, it's of course fine if you don't think it's worth doing. But to assert that it's universally not helpful to improve the syntax highlighting leaves me gobsmacked.

Comment: @KirkWoll WAT???  I think you must have misread my post.

Comment: @Matt, the OP said, and *you* quote, "it really helps anyone who visits the site".  You "disagree".

Comment: @KirkWoll simple logic misunderstanding.  The negation of `forall x. x` isn't `forall x. not x`, it's  `exists x. not x`.

Comment: @Matt, I'm sure you assumed that to be elucidating...

Comment: @Sifu I'm disagreeing with the assertion that "it **really** helps **anyone** who visits the site".  You and Kirk seem to think that by disagreeing, I'm asserting that "it **never** helps **anyone** who visits the site" (but I'm not).

Comment: Then, you "**agree** that it helps anyone who visits the site"? Do you really not agree only on the "**really**" modifier?

Comment: @KirkWoll actually, I had assumed that you would be interested in correctly understanding what I wrote.

Comment: @Sifu that's not the correct interpretation either.  What I'm actually saying is that at least one person who visits the site is not "really helped" by syntax highlighting.  Thus, that people are "really helped" by syntax highlighting, is not contradictory.

Comment: Excellent points!  Lots of people get obsesses with silly tools, which have **nothing to do with the actual problems of questions**.  This would be a much better site if people concentrated on technical problems... to the point where I think we need a penalty for frivolous edits.

Comment: Oh.. Then I think you should edit your answer accordingly so we can understand what you really meant `:)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was the reason why I posted the question, to get different points of view. And, I must state that I still disagree with your opinion. I would really prefer to have syntax highlight even in a 3-4 lines of HTML. I also believe that, sometimes, someone posts 3 or 4 blocks of code from different classes and it does help to spot the problems. In any case, we agree to disagree :)

Comment: I don't know why so many downvoted on this.. The user asked a question and @MattFenwick gave a reasonable answer. If your goal is to make each question as pleasing on the eyes as possible then sure do it. But Matt seems to be more interested in making edits that actually help in understanding the question OR actually answering the question. - downvote hype - luckily rep isn't a problem for you.