# Syntax highlight edit is unclearly presented in review

Tags: feature-request, documentation, rejected-edits

Often I suggest edits with only syntax highlight (adding `<!-- language: lang-... -->` comment). Normally it gets approved in questions and answers but in documentation it [got rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/121815?filter-tags=elm) and I understand why. Unless you choose `side-by-side markdown` representation this change is not visible. Given that documentation review is available for anyone above 200 rep I can see that not a lot of reviewers might even know syntax highlight exists.

As suggested in an [answer on syntax-highlight-only edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268337/do-you-edit-questions-in-order-to-provide-syntax-highlighting) I will move on. But maybe something can be done in changes review presentation to both: make an edit visible and make it obvious that such thing as syntax highlight exists for those who don't know about it?

**Update:**

I did add a separate [feature request on default highlight for elm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341319/add-syntax-highlight-default-for-tag-elm-currently-none). The point here is that hints for syntax highlights are not clearly displayed on default review page.

Answer (score 4):

The edit was rightfully rejected (albeit apparently for the wrong reason).

Elm is not one of [the languages for which Stack Overflow supports syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) (since it is [not among the supported languages in Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/tree/master/src)), and thus the `lang-elm` hint does not do anything special.

The edit could just have well added `<!-- language: lang-docsisfubar -->` and it would have had the same effect—namely, forcing the *default* parser to be used and thus essentially highlighting random stuff. Meaningless syntax highlighting is worse than no syntax highlighting.

If the Elm folks decide that they really like this "default" syntax highlighting scheme, they should ask for it to be applied globally to all Elm documentation examples, rather than editing in hints that look real but are really just placebos.

Comment: The rejection reasons were not very helpful either; the reviewers could have looked at the side-by-side markdown view to see what actually had changed.

Comment: This is not correct. If you look inside Elm-language documentation project you will see that it is supported. As well as in questions with `elm` tag.

Comment: Nope, @lonely. This is correct. You are seeing the same placebo effect in questions. Try it for yourself and see. Just put gibberish after `lang-`. Invalid identifiers revert back to "default". As I said, if the Elm community likes this "default" syntax highlighting, a moderator can make it the default (implied by the [tag:elm] tag) for you. Start a new Meta question to request it.

Comment: The question still remains. Not only my edit does change how this example looks but also provides future support for said example if elm highlight does appear. Vast majority of syntax-highlight-only edits does get approved. Which is good, I think. I personally like it highlighted. This one was rejected not because I used non-existant tag but because the change was not visible to reviewers.

Comment: I agree that the larger question remains, but you seem to be missing my point: **please stop adding hints to posts for syntax highlighting that does not exist**. @lonely

Comment: So you agree that your answer doesn't answer my question. I thank you for syntax highlight clarification I did make a [separate feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341319/add-syntax-highlight-default-for-tag-elm-currently-none). My point was that as it is clear from rejection reasons, review presentation for syntax highlight hints lacks clarity. Made an update to the question.