# Regarding the [down-votes] and [up-votes] tags - the line must *not* be drawn here!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, meta

## [tl;dr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tl;dr#Phrase):

I request that:

1. [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) is renamed to [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes).

   - [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes) is possibly added as a synonym for [downvotes](/questions/tagged/downvotes).
2. [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) is renamed to [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes).

   - [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes) is possibly added as a synonym for [upvotes](/questions/tagged/upvotes).

---

This follows directly from my question, [Can we downvote “down-vote” and “up-vote” in the Help Center and the associated tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382889/1364007) which (at the time of writing - five days after posting it) has a score of 108 (112 upvotes, 4 downvotes) meaning that either the community agrees that "downvote" and "upvote" and their variants should be favoured, or that my egregious usage of [freehand circles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/284827) was pleasing. I assume the former.

The main justification of the question was that "downvote" and "upvote" are far more commonly-used than "down-vote" and "up-vote" - by a ratio of more than 4:1 for both terms:

[image: MSO Stacked posts by term - unhyphenated wins]

The five questions for each tag with the highest scores also backs this up — not one (even the two with the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag) use "down-vote" or "up-vote" or their variants in either the title or the body:

- [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes):

  - [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/1364007)
  - [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/1364007)
  - [Enable Optional Anonymous Reasons for Downvotes on Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253531/1364007)
  - [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252270/1364007)
  - [Am I still supposed to explain my downvotes or not?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081/1364007)
- [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes):

  - [Why does it seem so hard to accumulate upvotes on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251084/1364007)
  - [Is it wrong to use an upvote to balance out a downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/1364007)
  - [Order highest upvoted answer before accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283456/1364007)
  - [Suspicious users found: active only one day, many upvotes cast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268267/1364007)
  - [I found users who appear to have been serially upvoted, why hasn't this been reversed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267837/1364007)

---

<sup>The title is a reference to [Picard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Luc_Picard)'s [monologue](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact) in [Star Trek: First Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_First_Contact): "*The line must be drawn here! This far, no further!*"</sup>

Comment: I really don't know whether to down-vote or downvote this question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels How about upv-oting it?

Comment: @Patrice: I already did (I think). No, wrong, I upvot-ed it

Comment: Don't be so hasty to assume. Freehand circles are **really** sexy. :)

Comment: I got a recent kicking on the main site for editing the regular expression terms "lookbehind" and "lookahead" into their hyphenated equivalents. I gave way on the correction, but grumbled about something to do with dictionary entries...

Comment: "Lookbehind" and "lookahead" (non-hyphenated forms) are correct in the context of regular expressions. You can't always determine usage rules from the dictionary. Dictionaries cite normal usage, not technical jargon. Also, more broadly, modern English (at least, American English) is disinclined to use hyphenated words. Most style guides recommend against it. If it works as a compound word, you should generally do that. (Note, e.g., "disinclined" vs. "dis-inclined".) Reserve hyphens for when you need to combine words to form a compound adjective for reasons of clarity. @halfer

Comment: Interesting @Cody, thanks; I'll look into that.

Comment: -U-p-v-o-t-e-d- for freehand circles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course. Sorry I was unable to do it sooner. You see, I was confused, because at the beginning of your question you had specified the [up-vote](/questions/tagged/up-vote) and [down-vote](/questions/tagged/down-vote) tags, when they were actually named with the plural forms. It took me a few minutes longer to find the actual tags to rename.

Sanity has now been restored. I don't know how those abhorrent hyphenated tag names ever snuck in there.

Comment: My usage of the non-plural forms was an atrocious oversight on my part. I've fixed the question. A thousand thanks for doing this so quickly.

Comment: On reflection, this sounds snarky, mostly because it's me. But this is actually 100% sincere. I couldn't agree with you more on the hyphen problem. You could have saved yourself a lot of work composing this question. I didn't need anywhere near this much convincing. :-)

Comment: No - you were right about the plural forms: it was copy-pasta from the *title* of the original question when I should have copy-pasted the tag markdown used later in the question. About the effort put into the question itself: while I'm very glad you agreed with me (I genuinely thought it'd be a week or before anything happened) I figured I'd try to put forward a convincing case to convince readers who might otherwise see the request as a waste of time and downvote it.